# do while loop - only looping twice - should be looping 8 times

Tags: java

This loop is only looping twice...

```
    int currentPosition = 10;
    int nextPosition;
    do
    {
        nextPosition = currentPosition + 1;
        sectionSem[nextPosition].P(); // wait for the section ahead to be
                                        // free
        trackSections[nextPosition] = "[A" + trainName + "]"; // move
                                                                // forward
        trackSections[currentPosition] = "[..]"; // clear section vacated
        // record the train activity
        theTrainActivity.addMovedTo(nextPosition);
        sectionSem[currentPosition].V(); // signal the section you vacated
                                            // now free
        currentPosition += 1;
    } while (currentPosition < 18);
```

Any idea why? It should be looping 8 times?!

Comment: What makes you think it's only looping twice?

Comment: Nothing in the code you have posted should cause the loop to terminate after only two iterations, although it is possible that something being *called* by one of the loop-body lines is doing something. Please provide more information.

Comment: Any Exceptions? (just a wild guess, but an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` may be what is generating the undesired result)

Comment: Also, have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Try adding [some output](https://ideone.com/806jo2) to verify it only runs twice.

Comment: It seams the reason is not `currentPosition` index. My be in other place you got exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code is somewhere in here:

```
    sectionSem[nextPosition].P(); // wait for the section ahead to be
                                    // free
    trackSections[nextPosition] = "[A" + trainName + "]"; // move
                                                            // forward
    trackSections[currentPosition] = "[..]"; // clear section vacated
    // record the train activity
    theTrainActivity.addMovedTo(nextPosition);
    sectionSem[currentPosition].V(); // signal the section you vacated
                                        // now free
```

If you boil the loop down to just this:

```
public static void main(String []args){
        int currentPosition = 10;
        int nextPosition;
        do
        {
            nextPosition = currentPosition + 1;         
            System.out.println("nextPosition = " + currentPosition);
            currentPosition += 1;
            System.out.println("currentPosition = " + currentPosition);
        } while (currentPosition < 18);
     }
```

It runs 8 times. The output is as follows:

```
nextPosition = 10
currentPosition = 11
nextPosition = 11
currentPosition = 12
nextPosition = 12
currentPosition = 13
nextPosition = 13
currentPosition = 14
nextPosition = 14
currentPosition = 15
nextPosition = 15
currentPosition = 16
nextPosition = 16
currentPosition = 17
nextPosition = 17
currentPosition = 18
```